# Why is can't use overriding method in C#? (not about keyword)

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

```
public abstract class A
{
    public void CallMe() { Console.WriteLine("I am A."); }
}

public class B : A
{
    new public void CallMe() { Console.WriteLine("I am B."); }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new B();
        a.CallMe();
    }
}
```

output is "I am A."

Why this happening? Is this reasonable?

compiled by Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: You didn't actually override, the `new` keyword hides. Use `override`

Comment: @user3576363 It didn't change the result because you're calling it as type `A`. If you did `B b = new B(); b.CallMe();` instead, you'd see the `B` message. As to "why" it works that way, it's because that's how it's designed to work.

Comment: And `virtual` in the base

Comment: "new" means "I wish this to be a new method of the same name as an old one, and not an overriding of the old one". If that's not what you mean, don't say that. You're calling the old method.

Comment: The compiler already told you that you were doing it wrong.  You added "new" to shut up the compiler, but that didn't stop you from doing it wrong.  Next time, google the error message first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the `CallMe()` method in your base class `virtual` and then use the `override` modifier in `B`:

```
public abstract class A
{
    public virtual void CallMe() { Console.WriteLine("I am A."); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void CallMe() { Console.WriteLine("I am B."); }
}
```

Comment: @user it is not different from Java at all. Java methods are just always virtual unless declared final.

Answer (score 0):

`B.CallMe()` does not override `A.CallMe()`, it shadows or hides `A.CallMe()`.  Since `CallMe` is a non-virtual method the compiler chooses which method to call based on the compile time type of the `a` variable.  Since the the compile time type of `a` is `class A` it will call `A.CallMe()`.

If you want it to call `B.CallMe()` you need to use the `virtual` keyword on `A.CallMe()` which will enable virtual dispatch where the application will call the `CallMe()` method based on the runtime type of `a` which is `class B`.

See [Hiding through inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: *it shadows or hides `B.CallMe()`* Not that way, it is other way around.