# Why the output of following program is => BC::Display BC::Display BC::Display

Tags: c#, overriding

```
class BC
{
    public virtual void Display()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("BC::Display");
    }
}

class DC : BC
{
    public virtual void Display()
    {

        System.Console.WriteLine("DC::Display");

    }
}

class TC : DC
{
    public virtual void Display()
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("TC::Display");
    }
}



class Program
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       BC b;
       b = new BC();
       b.Display();

       b = new DC();
       b.Display();

       b = new TC();
       b.Display();


   }
}
```

why output is not "BC::Display DC::Display TC::Display"?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313408/why-is-cant-use-overriding-method-in-c-not-about-keyword?rq=1

Comment: The compiler warnings give a hint to why this is happening. You are hiding the inherited members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you compile it in Visual Studio, you'll get these warnings:

```
Warning 2   'Workbench.Program.DC.Display()' hides inherited member 'Workbench.Program.BC.Display()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword. C:\Users\Alberti\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Workbench\Workbench\Program.cs   328 29  Workbench
Warning 3   'Workbench.Program.TC.Display()' hides inherited member 'Workbench.Program.DC.Display()'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword. C:\Users\Alberti\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Workbench\Workbench\Program.cs   338 29  Workbench
```

You must use `override` instead of `virtual` in `DC` and `TC`, otherwise you are doing a `new virtual` and creating a new method that isn't "overriding" the `BC.Display` but that is simply "hiding" it.

There is a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6162547/613130 about the difference between `virtual/override` and `new`

Answer (score 0):

Only the method in the base class needs to be marked `virtual`.  The methods in the derived classes should be marked as `override`, otherwise they hide the underlying methods.  Since they're "different" methods, and `b` is of type `BC`, the compiler will route all calls to `BC.Display`.